# jquery дождаться ajax ответа

Tags: javascript, jquery

Почему не работает?

```
function request(url, data) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'post',
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise();
};
```

Возвращаемый результат пустой ajax объект (как я понимаю)...

Comment: console.log(data) что показывает?

Comment: @EatMyDust Object {}
always:()
done:()
fail:()
pipe:()
progress:()
promise:(a)state:
()
then:()
__proto__:Object

Comment: он не пустой, а что вы ожидаете в нем? Вы выводите его еще до того, как ответ асинхронной функции придет от сервера.

Comment: @Jean-Claude resolve находится в success() и отработать как я понимаю должен по success и вернуть ответ, а возвращается не то, что хотелось

Comment: а что должно возвращаться?

Comment: @Jean-Claude ответ с сервера (данные)?

Comment: во-первых, $.ajax и так промис возвращает, не надо свой deferred создавать. во-вторых, где и как вы ждете ответа?

Comment: @YuraIvanov хочу вернуть ответ сервера из функции

Comment: Из аякса ничего вернуть нельзя, недавно был такой вопрос, внутри него можно выполнить внешнюю фцнкцию или присвоить данные во внешнюю переменную, вот так работает http://jsbin.com/fofanelalo/edit?js,output

Comment: Разбор вопроса наиболее раскрыт тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call